# PHP output_buffering option

Tags: php

Having following code:

```
ob_start();
echo "Hello</br>";
ob_end_clean();
```

and disabling *output control* in *php.ini* file
`output_buffering = On` doesn't change the thing - i the output buffering is still working - the Hello string isn't outputted meaningd that switching *output_buffering* option to On/Off makes no results.

Comment: Did you restart PHP after changing the ini file?

Comment: Yes, of course. Any other idea?

Comment: Are you running in webserver or CLI? CLI always has output buffering enabled.